# Getting age for all the dates in a month Postgresql query

Tags: postgresql, birt, generate-series

I have an Installed capacity date which is wcc_from_date. Here I wants to get age for all the dates in May 2020. I am trying with following query

```
SELECT DATE_PART('year', AGE((select wwoc_date 
                               FROM wb_water_op_charge_detail, 
                                    wb_water_op_charge_master 
                               where to_char(wwoc_date, 'MM YYYY') = '05 2020' 
                                 and wwoc_internal_id = wwoc_ref_id), wcc_from_date)) AS years 
FROM wb_installed_capacity
```

but it is returning me following error

> ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
> SQL state: 21000

How I can pass each dates in AGE function and get 31 sets of Age?

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please review [ask]. Following that as a template for your question greatly enhances your chance of getting a satisfactory answer. In this case please post table definition (ddl) and sample test data, as text - **no images**, and expected results of that data.

Comment: How is `wb_installed_capacity` related to the other two tables? You are probably just looking for a proper JOIN between all three of them. I would at least expect the sub-query to be a co-related sub-query, i.e. referencing one of the columns from the `wb_installed_capacity` table. But as you didn't prefix your columns with the table names it's impossible to tell which column belongs to which table.

Answer (score 0):

This means your nested SELECT returns more than one row.

```
ERROR: more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression SQL state: 21000
```

You need to add a proper WHERE clause to it or use LIMIT 1 to the subquery.